# How to determine whether a classifier like adaboost is weak?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-mining, svm, boosting

I run the cross-validation experiment for a given data set, and tried two different approaches: one is based on SVM, another is based on SVM plus Adaboost. But the confusion matrix for two experiments are exactly the same. I am confused on how to explain this kind of result. Adaboost is supposed to start with a weak classifier, but how to determine whether a classifier is weak?

Comment: How do you apply AdaBoost to SVM, do you change the weights of points in optimized function every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can answer the second question. A weak classifier for AdaBoost means a classifier with low Variance (and consequently high bias) in Bias-Variance decomposition. The reason is, that combining classifiers increases variance, so when you start with high variance classifiers, you're very likely to overfit.

Comment: I think your definition of a weak classifier is accurate with regard to the earliest papers on boosting, but that low variance isn't necessarily a good thing for base classifiers. For example, Schapire et al. said in 1997 that "The original goal of boosting was to reduce the error of so-called “weak” learning algorithms which tend to have very large bias," but that boosting high-variance classifiers also worked, which is why boosting trees is so popular these days. http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~isbell/tutorials/boostingmargins.pdf

Comment: Also, combining classifiers--especially if they're unstable--will usually decrease the variance, not increase it as you stated.  That's why bagging works, as discussed in the same pdf I just linked.

Comment: I haven't yet read the whole paper, but it's excellent and conveys some really usefull information, thank you. I'll update my answer regarding to it when I finish.