# AdaBoost assumption of weak classifier

Tags: machine-learning, classification, overfitting, adaboost

I've read and think I got a good grasp of the math behind AdaBoost, but I wasn't able to understand *why* AdaBoost requires a weak base-classifier?

Specifically, I'm dealing with AdaBoost using decision-tree as base-classifier. So, what if my DT wasn't "weak"? So instead of using a stump (DT with depth of 1), what should happen with AdaBoost if I used deeper tree for example?

I found [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33424/how-to-determine-whether-a-classifier-like-adaboost-is-weak), but I'm not it fully answers my question

Comment: Where are you seeing that a weak base-classifier is required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Practically, I'm unsure why one would need to rely on AdaBoost if we already had a strong classifier. **Tl;dr: I don't believe that having a weak learner is requirement for AdaBoost to work.**

I can try to walk through some of the analysis. We'll deal with empirical error, and then generalization error.

**Empirical Error (train)**

We define a weak learner as any classifier with error rate $\frac{1}{2} - \gamma$ for $\gamma \in (0, \frac{1}{2})$. In the case you're worried about, $\gamma$ is close to $\frac{1}{2}$.

Let $J(\theta^{(i)})$ be the error of AdaBoost after $i$ rounds; we can prove the following rate-of-convergence result:

$$J(\theta^{(i+1)}) \leq \sqrt{1 - 4\gamma^2} J(\theta^{(i)})$$.

This is proven by Duchi [here](http://cs229.stanford.edu/extra-notes/boosting.pdf). So if we denote $\gamma$ for the weak learner after round $i$ as $\gamma_i$, we can write
$$J(\theta^{(T)}) \leq \prod_{t=1}^T \sqrt{1 - 4\gamma_t^2} \leq exp\left(-2 \sum_{t=1}^T \gamma_t^2\right) \leq exp\left(-2\gamma^2T\right)$$
for $\gamma = \underset{t}{\min}\gamma_t$. So, basically, the empirical error vanishes exponentially. Note that this occurs regardless of $\gamma$; it simply trades off with $T$, so we don't necessarily need a particular type of weak learner, just any classifier with better-than-random error rate.

**Generalization Error (test)**

Dealing with generalization error is a little bit past my mathematical abilities. But, using basic statistical learning theory, it's a result from Vapnik (1971) that 
$$\varepsilon(h) \leq \hat{\varepsilon}(h) + O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\sqrt{d\log\frac{m}{d} + \log\frac{1}{\delta}}\right)$$ 
for classifiers under the empirical risk minimization (ERM) learning framework with high probability ($1-\delta$). Note $d = VC(\mathcal{H})$, the VC-dimension of the hypothesis class of $H$. We can treat AdaBoost this way since it is a classifier that tries to minimize some empirical risk (i.e. training loss) on a training dataset (this is hand-wavey, but the definition of ERM isn't the point here). I believe the notes [here](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring08/cos511/scribe_notes/0305.pdf) build on these principles and show a similar bound on the generalization error of Adaboost, that is;

$$\varepsilon(h) \leq \hat{\varepsilon}(h) + O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\sqrt{\frac{\log m\log|\mathcal{H}|}{\theta^2} + \log\frac{1}{\delta}}\right)$$

where they treat Adaboost as a max-margin classifier with margin $\theta$; unfortunately, I don't think I'll be much help in elucidating this particular formula. Note, however, that **there is no dependence on $\gamma$ here** except in the first $\hat{\varepsilon}(h)$ term, which vanishes regardless of $\gamma$ as $T \to \infty$. So a particular type of weak learner is again unnecessary -- we just need a better-than-random learner.

Comment: I agree. The interesting thing about AdaBoost is that it works *even with* weak learners, which is not a trivial fact (though I think it's less interesting a fact than I did when I first saw it)

Comment: Thanks a lot - this really cleared this up for me. Everywhere I read about AdaBoost it started out with weak-classifiers, but I wasn't sure this is an actual requirement for the algorithm. As you showed, it isn't really. I'll chew some more on the math - thanks!